# Styling button-column in Yii CGridview to wrap content with <div> tag inside <td>

Tags: yii

Currently my buttons in table column comes like this

```
<td>
 <a href="#"/>Edit</a>
 <a href="#"/>Veiw</a>
 <a href="#"/>Delete</a>
</td>
```

I want it to do like

```
<td>
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="#"/>Edit</a>
 <a href="#"/>Veiw</a>
 <a href="#"/>Delete</a>
</div>
</td>
```

Please suggest some way to configure it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to customize cgidview code as below:

> array(
>
> ```
> 'class' => 'YouCSSClass',
> 'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
>
> ),
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the column template of your Grid

```
        'template' => '<div class="wrapper"><a>{view}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{update} {delete}</div>'
```

Finally your grid view will come some thing like

```
         $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ..................
            ..................
            'columns'=>array(
                ...............
                ...............
                'template' => '<div class="wrapper"><a>{view}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{update} {delete}</div>',
                ...............
                )
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please customize your CGridView buttons on views file like this.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    ---
    'columns'=>array(
        ---
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                    'template' => '<div class="wrapper">{view}{update}{delete}</div>',
        ),
    ),
));
```